# DRF regex search on all fields

Tags: django, rest

I need DRF '$'- regex search on all(`"__all__"`) fields of a model in Django Rest API Framework.

I can specify like `search_fields = ['$username', '$first_name', '$email', '$last_name']` this on all fields explicitly on a model.

but I need $-regex search on all fields of a model something like `search_fields = '$__all__'`.

Please anybody giude me on this , Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of all the fields in a model, you can use

```
[field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]
```

You can add checks while building up the list of the fields:

```
[field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields() if field.name.startswith("$")]
```